# Implicitly unwrapped optional strange behaviour with map

Tags: swift, option-type

### What I discovered

This question is about something I noticed a bit strange in the `Swift` language. I came across this behaviour, as it was a bug in my code.

If I created an array for a grid as an implicitly unwrapped optional, then `map` behaves strangely. Have a look at this code:

```
let grid: [[Int]]! = [ // May be defined like this if set later on
[1, 2, 3],
[4, 5, 6],
[7, 8, 9]
]


print(grid.map { $0[0] }!)
// Prints "[1, 2, 3]" (not what I wanted)

print(grid!.map { $0[0] })
// Prints "[1, 4, 7]" (what I wanted)
```

I know the row can be obtained simply by doing `grid[0]`. However, I am trying to get a column.

I tried the first method above, which only gives the row instead of the column. The second method worked and gave the column.

### What is the cause?

I defined `grid` as `[[Int]]!`, which is an implicitly unwrapped optional.

- Why do I need to force unwrap `grid` to use `map` properly?
- Why does the first method act the same as returning a row using `grid[0]`?

Comment: Should it be `[[Int]]!` instead of `[[Int]]`?

Comment: @AhmadF It is defined as `[[Int]]!`. This is because, as the comment says, it may be set later on. It could be declared as `var grid: [[Int]]!`, and then set later.

Comment: Apart from your main question, I suggest you extract out this "settable but only once" pattern into a separate type, so that you can "tuck away" the optionalness, https://forums.swift.org/t/assign-a-variable-a-value-once-then-make-it-read-only/23056/4?u=alexanderm

Comment: @Alexander I honestly don't think it's worth extra code to do that. I'll stick with just `var`, it's a lot neater.

Comment: @George_E It depends on how often you're doing it. Generally the "set mandatorily set at least once" pattern is pretty common. At 2 uses, I would consider it, at 3 I would strongly recommend it. Lines of code don't determine complexity. Most times, the "simpler" solution is actually longer, because it does a good job in abstracting away details.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two versions of `map`: one that operates on the array and one that operates on *optionals*.

Your `grid` is an *optional*, and even though it is an *implicitly unwrapped optional (IUO)* it is still an *optional*.  Swift will treat an IUO as an *optional* whenever possible and only force unwraps the value when the unwrapped type is needed.

Because of this, the *optional* version of `map` is used instead of the one you expect.  By explicitly unwrapping `grid` with `!`, you then allow the desired version of `map` to be used.

**How does `map` work on an *optional*?**

When map is applied to an *optional*, it applies the closure to the unwrapped value.  If the *optional* is `nil`, nothing happens.

So, `grid` is unwrapped and becomes `$0`, and the closure returns `$0[0]` which is the first row of the `grid`.

---

**Note:** In Xcode, if you <kbd>option</kbd>-click on `map` in each statement you will see that the first says:

> Evaluates the given closure when this Optional instance is not nil,
>   passing the unwrapped value as a parameter.

and the second one:

> Returns an array containing the results of mapping the given closure
>   over the sequence’s elements.

Comment: You're welcome.  I think the Swift designers could have avoided this confusion by naming the `map` that works on optionals as something else.

Comment: Yeah, it took me ages to figure out the bug, as I was making a sudoku solver. It only checked rows, as the columns weren't getting checked  It should be renamed to `mapOpt` or something like that.

Comment: I think it is named `map` because both optional and array are functors, and `map` is common name for functors in functional languages (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Functor_(functional_programming))